Import .sav into R and let the systematic missings (empty spaces) not be shown as NA's
I want to import a .sav dataset ofa survey into R. The problem for me is that nnot all people are being asked all questions but I do not know which people get asked which question.
SPSS just shows empty spaces (or nearly empty with a "." in it) if a person was not asked a specific question (systematic missing). When importing the dataset to R these empty spaces are just read as NA's.
The problem now is, that I can't distinguish between those systematic missings and the NA's that are created due to the fact that people answered "I don't know". This is problematic for my calculation and plotting, because instead of an n of 1000 with like 50 missings I now have an n of 2000 with 1050 missings.
Do you guys know how to solve this problem and how to let R know, that the systematic missings should be labelled as 998 for example?
I imported the data with the help of the haven package:
data <- read_sav("path")

Now I want NA's to be treated as NA's and the systematic missings as 998 or I just like to identify the systematic missings as themselves. All other values should be treated the same as in the .sav file.
Can you help me out here?
Thank you for your answers!
